# What can I do with all my extra TL-49 fuses?

Tags: mafia-3

I have wire tapped all the junction boxes around New Bordeaux and still have over 150 TL-49 fuses crammed into my pockets.

There are still a plenty of the damn things scattered around the city and my OCD is forcing me to continually stop and collect them. It is making the game take waaaay longer than necessary.

There doesn't seem to be a trophy / achievement for collecting them all so am I wasting my time or is there anything else I can do with them?

Comment: All I could find is [this steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/360430/discussions/0/341537671994075619/) and the one player said that  it was basically a waste of time to get them all and are just extra it seems.

Comment: @TimmyJim I now have over 200 of them and there are still more out there. It very weird that they would have that many extra lying around with no use for them.

Answer (score 1):

After a few missions, the Consigliere will help identify characters such as allies and villains on the map, and since that happened I have had no need for using those fuses or wiretapping. I completed the game today.

So there's most probably no other use for those extra ones.